# Code once for multi-platform mobile apps in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, dry

I've been looking in a bit to phonegap, and a lot of other mobile app making solutions. As phonegap claims to support the biggest variety of technologies, it seems very attractive. However, when finding the getting started guides, there are separate guides for developing for iPhone, Android, et.c.

So I wonder what the approach is for developing cross platform apps? Is it possible to write code once and use on all platforms that phonegap supports? Do you write in pure html/css/js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot has been written already on PhoneGap vs 'native' (vs Titanium and others) [See the 'Related' bar on the right]. The reason for the separate guides is that you need these specific environments to finally build your application (merge your html/css/js with PhoneGaps platform specific code). PhoneGap Build tries to remedy this: it builds the app for you (as a web service).

The development itself happens in html/css/js. Your js code will have access to functionality that normally is not available to js on the phone (such as the camera), via an interface provided by a bunch of PhoneGap code that is different for each platform. If PhoneGap doesn't provide certain functionality you might add this yourself (or find a third party plugin that does this), but this requires you to write code that is platform dependent. At the time I used this I wasn't able to use custom libraries via PhoneGap Build (the web tool that builds for you).

Personally, I have left the idea of PhoneGap altogether. You don't have native 'UI', but are instead left with what you can do in HTML/css/js. In my opinion this is not only limited in many ways (regarding looks and speed), it is also less 'straightforward' and 'stable'. This results in many weird and hard to solve 'bugs' (the app works, but as soon as the user doesn't move and tap his/her finger in the 'expected' way, glitches appear, and I don't like that, personally). Solving these takes a lot of time and I find it not fun to do. And I am talking single phone, single platform here. You can imagine what happens if you try this on another.

Furthermore, using PhoneGap makes you dependent on yet another third party (PhoneGap that is). Also, you produce code and learn skills that, on mobile level, and in my opinion, are less 'standard' and thus less reusable and I doubt if that will change soon. Support and documentation is also less and the same holds true for tooling. And finally, developing native code brings you much closer to the actual platform and I think this is important because they each have their strengths, weaknesses and peculiarities.

Android and iOS now account for 85% of the smartphones sold. So currently, my strategy is to target those two. The learning curve surely is bigger, especially if you come from the web and have html/css/js skills already. But once 'up to par' I think developing an app twice native can compete with all the debugging that PhoneGap requires, timewise (given that you want at least some level of decency in your PhoneGap app). And quality wise, your native apps will be better. For sure.

But well, that is just one opinion and also one that might change over time. I based my strategy (to focus on native development) mainly on my experience with PhoneGap. There are other approaches as well, such as Titanium, that have different pros and cons, and you might at least take a look those as well.

Edit: sorry about the long rant. Needless to say that the relevance of it and whether the same will hold true for you, entirely depends on where you are coming from (skills and such) and where you are going to (whether sticking to one or two platforms is even an option).